# calculating hazard function for the standard normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, hazard

Based on formulas given in the [Mathematica UUPDE database](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/02/01/the-ultimate-univariate-probability-distribution-explorer/)
I've plotted the hazard function for the standard normal distribution in R.

It seems to be correct in certain range; the numerical issues occur for larger values, see attached figure. Below is the complete R code.

Any comments would be very appreciated.

[image: PDF, CDF, HF and SF plots for standard normal distribution]

```
PDF = function(x) {  1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-x^2/2) }
erf <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1
erfc <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2), lower = FALSE)
CDF = function(x) {  1/2 * (1 + erf(x/(sqrt(2)))) }
HF = function(x) { sqrt(2/pi)/(exp(x^2/2)*(2-erfc(-x/sqrt(2)))) }
SF = function(x) { 1 - 1/2 *erfc(-x/sqrt(2)) }

par(mar=c(3,3,1.5,0.5), oma=c(0,0,0,0), mgp=c(2,1,0))
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

x = seq(from = -4,to = 10,by = .001)

##### PDF
a = PDF(x)
plot(x,a,'l',main='',ylab="PDF",xlab="x")
grid(nx = NULL,ny = NULL,col = "grey",lty = "dotted",lwd = par("lwd"),equilogs = TRUE)

##### CDF
a = CDF(x)
plot(x,a,'l',main='',ylab="CDF",xlab="x")
grid(nx = NULL,ny = NULL,col = "grey",lty = "dotted",lwd = par("lwd"),equilogs = TRUE)

##### HF
a = HF(x)
plot(x,a,'l',main='',ylab="HF",xlab="x")
grid(nx = NULL,ny = NULL,col = "grey",lty = "dotted",lwd = par("lwd"),equilogs = TRUE)

##### SF
a = SF(x)
plot(x,a,'l',main='',ylab="SF",xlab="x")
grid(nx = NULL,ny = NULL,col = "grey",lty = "dotted",lwd = par("lwd"),equilogs = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you need arbitrary precision or are you interested in a specific range only?

Comment: Side note: it's interesting to me that you opted to use the built in normal cdf function to get the erf function and then use that to bake your own cdf function.

Comment: @Roland I was merely interested in a correct hazard function plot in general and wondered what went wrong

Comment: @Dason, admittedly it's a quite inefficient way to use R on my side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hazard function is the density function divided by the survivor function. The problem with your code is that you are taking this definition at face value and doing a simple division operation; when both the numerator and the denominator are very small values (on the order of 1e-300), which happens in the tail of the distribution, this operation becomes numerically unstable. For this kind of problem, the more appropriate solution is to compute the *logarithms* of the numerator and denominator (which are moderate-sized negative numbers rather than tiny numbers), subtract the log-denominator from the log-numerator, then exponentiate.

R provides all the pieces you need to do this calculation. You can get the survivor function via `pnorm(x,lower=FALSE)`; you can get the density and the survivor functions on the log scale by using `log=TRUE` and `log.p=TRUE` in `dnorm()` and `pnorm()` respectively.  So:

```
HF <- function(x) {
   exp(dnorm(x,log=TRUE)-pnorm(x,lower=FALSE,log.p=TRUE))
}
curve(HF,from=-4,to=10)
```

[image]

This strategy can be generalized to compute the hazard function for any distribution provided the log-density and log-survivor functions are available (in general for a distribution `foo` R provides density function `dfoo` and CDF `pfoo` which can be substituted above).

Comment: Thanks, very useful comments!

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.